# Warn when using parameter marked as __unused

Tags: c, clang

Using the -Wunused-parameter flag, you can enforce __unused for unused parameters, as a compiler optimization. The following code causes two warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

These warnings are fixed by adding __unused the unused arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int __unused argc, char __unused **argv) {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When you use a parameter marked __unused, clang 4.1 does not warn or error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int __unused argc, char __unused **argv) {
  printf("hello world. there are %d args\n", argc);
  return 0;
}
```

The same behavior is exhibited using `__attribute__((unused))`.

```
int main(int __attribute__((unused)) argc, char __attribute__((unused)) **argv) {
```

Is there a way to warn or error on __unused? What would happen should you accidentally leave an __unused on a used parameter? In the above example `argc` appears to have the correct value, although it could be the compiler not taking advantage of the hint, and I wouldn't rely on this behavior without more understanding.

Comment: I've substantially edited the question to use C sample code instead of Objective-C to demonstrate that this is a C language question. Also, noted that the flag is -Wextra instead of -Wunused.

Comment: It's actually the `-Wunused-parameter` flag that's relevant here.  The `-Wextra` flag enables `-Wunused-parameter` if `-Wunused` is specified, which is also implied by `-Wall`, but `-Wextra` is not enough by itself.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `__attribute__((deprecated))`, which will warn when something is used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `__unused` attribute is intended to **prevent** complaints when arguments to functions/methods or functions/methods are unused, not to enforce their lack of use.

The term used in the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) is:

> This attribute, attached to a function, means that the function is meant to be possibly unused

And [for variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes):

> This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused.

The most common use is for development against an interface - e.g. callbacks, where you may be forced to accept several parameters but don't make use of all of them.

I use it a bit when I'm doing test driven development - my initial routine takes some parameters and does nothing, so all the parameters take `__attribute__((unused))`. As I develop it I make use of the parameters. At the end of development I remove them from the method, and see what shakes out.

Comment: My understanding is that it was a compiler hint, that you don't necessarily need the value to be available, which should cause issues if you're using it. I get the same behavior with `__attribute__((unused))`.

Comment: It's not an optimization hint - calling conventions would require the parameter to be present. In the same way as declaring a `register` variable should not result in an error if you don't have any registers left to use.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to skin this cat is to remove (or comment out) the name of the parameter.

```
int main ( int argc, char ** /* argv */ ) {
    printf("hello world. there are %d args\n", argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the compiler won't warn about `argv` being unused, and you *can't* use it, because it has no name.

Comment: This, for me, is definitely the way to go: the compiler doesn't need to know nor care; and you physically cannot use the parameters you want to leave unused! Be sure to note this convention down somewhere though so that it's not mistaken for sloppy programming.

Comment: Clang/LLVM doesn't like this --- I get a "Parameter name omitted" error and I can't find any compiler flag that might disable this. Petesh's answer works well, though.

Comment: @big_m: I suspect there's something else going on here, because I use code just like that all the time. Can you post some code?

Comment: @Marshall, I created a new command-line project in Xcode (4.6.3), pasted in your code above, and I got a "Parameter name omitted" error, same as I get in my existing projects. Are you using Clang? I'm sure I've seen this work with other compilers in the past; I was just giving my experience with Clang/Xcode.

Comment: @big_m: Sorry - I see what's going on. I was building with C++ enabled. If I build with C, then I get the "parameter name omitted". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's an interesting find, @Marshall. An error for C (and functions in Objective-C), but not for C++. Odd. Perhaps it's part of the C++ language definition. In any case, I think it's great to have all the options documented here.

Comment: This is apparently a gcc/clang extension, not part of standard C.  Oddly it is not included in the documentation of gcc's extensions; they are usually pretty good about that.  But compiling with `-pedantic` gives a warning with both gcc and clang.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `deprecated` and `unused` together to achieve the desired behavior (thanks to Dietrich Epp for mentioning `deprecated` in his comment):

```
#define is_unused __attribute__((deprecated, unused))
```

When the entity is actually unused, this will silence the warning. When an entity is flagged with this macro but still used, you'll get a deprecation warning.