# How to enforce parameters of anonymous blocks to be unused in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, enforcement, unused-variables

I've run into a situation while using a library called [TransitionKit](https://github.com/blakewatters/TransitionKit) (helps you write state machines) where I am want to supply entry and exit actions in the form of a callback.

Sadly, the callbacks include two completely useless parameters. A typical block has to look like this:

```
^void (TKState *state, TKStateMachine *stateMachine) {
    // I TOTALLY don't want parameters `state` or `stateMachine` used here
};
```

(this is an anonymous code block. Read up on blocks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201774/590767) if you're unclear)

As I've noted in the comment, I really don't want those parameters even mentioned in the body there. I've tried simply removing the parameter names like suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572086/590767) like so:

```
^void (TKState *, TKStateMachine *) {
     // I foobar all I like here
};
```

but sadly the code won't compile then :(.

How can I enforce this non-usage of parameters in code?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I could come up with. Quite a hack and relies on the `GCC poison` pragma, which is not standard but a GNU extension - although, given that you are probably compiling this with `clang` anyway, it should not be a problem.

```
#define _state state
#define _stateMachine stateMachine

#pragma GCC poison state stateMachine
```

Then this compiles:

```
^(TKState *_state, TKStateMachine *_stateMachine) {
    do_something();
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
^(TKState *_state, TKStateMachine *_stateMachine) {
    do_something(state, stateMachine);
}
```

Comment: I've not tried this myself with `clang` but I trust that it will probably work. It doesn't seem like a general solution :/

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a function that took one kind of block, and returned another, like this:

```
@class TKState, TKStateMachine; // here so this will compile

typedef void (^LongStateBlock)(TKState *state, TKStateMachine *stateMachine);

static inline LongStateBlock Adapter(void(^block)()) {

    void(^heapBlock)() = [block copy]; // forces block to be on heap rather than stack, a one-time expense

    LongStateBlock longBlock = ^(TKState *s __unused, TKStateMachine *sm __unused) {
        heapBlock();
    };

    // this is the non-ARC, MRR version; I'll leave ARC for the interested observer
    [heapBlock release];
    return [[longBlock copy] autorelease];
}
```

And in practice:

```
// this represents a library method
- (void)takesLongStateBlock:(LongStateBlock)longBlock
{
    // which hopefully wouldn't look exactly like this
    if (longBlock) longBlock(nil, nil);
}

- (void)yourRandomMethod
{
    [self takesLongStateBlock:^(TKState *state, TKStateMachine *stateMachine) {
        NSLog(@"Gratuitous parameters, AAAAHHHH!");
    }];

    [self takesLongStateBlock:Adapter(^{
        NSLog(@"So, so clean.");
    })];

}
```

The whole thing is [gisted](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/9646508), and should compile inside any class. It does what you expect when you call `-yourRandomMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do what you want when you are creating a block, you can only miss the parameter names when you are declaring a block variable(a reference to a block, to avoid misunderstandings)

So here you can miss the param names:

```
void (^myBlock)(SomeClass *);
```

But not when you create a block:

```
myBlock = ^(SomeClass *o)
{
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write

```
^void (TKState *unused_state, TKStateMachine *unused_stateMachine) {
    // Anyone using unused_state or unused_stateMachine gets what they deserve.
};
```

Of course someone *can* use the parameters. But then whatever you do, they can change the code. If someone is intent on shooting themselves in the foot, there is no stopping them.